# R run 2 different blocks of code at the same time (in parallel)

Tags: r

Is there a way to run 2 different blocks of code at the same time.  I have been looking at parallel packages within R and they all appear to be based on running the same function in a loop.  I am looking for a way to run different functions at the same time (1 iteration of the loop).  For example, I would like to create a model on a certain data object at the same time as creating another model on a different object.  I could do this by starting another instance of R but would rather keep it all in the same script.  Is this possible?  I appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 3):

You could try substituting/quoting the functions then evaluating them in parallel.

```
library(parallel)
ExpressionVect <- c(substitute(function1()), 
                substitute(function2()))

mclapply(ExpressionVect, eval, mc.cores= 2)
```

This allows the functions to be evaluated in parallel when they are independent functions

Answer (score 0):

You can use `clusterMap`, which is a parallel version of `mapply`. This assumes you want to fit the same type of model on each node (lm, glm, rpart, whatever).

```
clus <- makeCluster(2)
out <- clusterMap(clus, lm, formula=list(speed ~ dist, mpg ~ cyl + disp + hp),
                            data=list(cars, mtcars))
```

Comment: Thanks Hong, but I also have some more code that needs to run other than just model creation.  I basically have two rather long functions that include model creation in each.  Any ideas?