# Make 2 functions run at the same time and in parallel?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scrapy, ipython-parallel

I have an array

```
myArray = array(url1,url2,...,url90)
```

I want to execute this commande 3 times in parallel

`scrapy crawl mySpider -a links=url`

and each time with 1 url,

```
scrapy crawl mySpider -a links=url1
scrapy crawl mySpider -a links=url2
scrapy crawl mySpider -a links=url3
```

and when the first one finish his job, he will get the other url like

```
scrapy crawl mySpider -a links=url4
```

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519431/r-run-2-different-blocks-of-code-at-the-same-time-in-parallel), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957116/make-2-functions-run-at-the-same-time)  and I try this:

```
import threading
from threading import Thread

def func1(url):

    scrapy crawl mySpider links=url

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myArray = array(url1,url2,...,url90)
    for(url in myArray):
        Thread(target = func1(url)).start()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `target = func1(url)` you actually runnig `func1` and passing result to `Thread` (not a reference do the function). This means functions are run on the loop not in the seperate thread.

You need to rewrite it like that:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    myArray = array(url1,url2,...,url90)
    for(url in myArray):
        Thread(target=func1, args=(url,))).start()
```

Then you are telling Thread to run `func1` with arguments `(url,)`

Also you should wait for Threads to finish after the loop, otherwise your program with terminate just after starting all the threads.

EDIT:
and if you want only 3 threads to be run on the same time you may want to use ThreadPool:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

    pool = ThreadPool(processes=3)
    pool.map(func, myArray)
```

Comment: When the first one finished his job, does he recieve another url? , in your edit you didn't write the "for loop"

Comment: Yes - ThreadPools creates 3 Threads and `pool.map` runs `func` for every element from `myArray` using this threads. So when one thread finishes its job it runs `func` with next url from `myArray`. In this case you don'tneed to write 'for loop' as `map` functions runs one internally.